# Compare 1 field from sub query against other?

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I am trying to compare two fields in oracle select query as part of case statement one of which is coming from sub query but I get error.

E.g

```
select 1 as one, 
       (select 2 from dual) as two,
       case when one=two then 'EQUAL'
            else 'NOTEQUAL'
       end match
from dual;
```

Error ORA-00904: TWO invalid identifier

Thoughts how can rewrite this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need nested select and then compare for equality.

Comment: one and two column aliases are not in scope for the case statement.  So it doesn't know what one or two are you can either use the full expresion in the case OR use the case in an outer query.

Answer (score 2):

You cant use the alias, so you have to rewrite the data source and subquery.

```
SELECT 1 as one,
       (SELECT 2 FROM dual) as two,
       CASE WHEN 1 = (SELECT 2 FROM dual)
            THEN 'EQUAL'
            ELSE 'NOTEQUAL' 
        END match
  FROM dual
```

Result

```
one two match
1   2   NOTEQUAL
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you cant use the alias on the same level, you need to do a subquery or a cte

```
WITH step1 as (
    select 1 as one
    from dual
), step2 as (
    select 2 as two
    from dual
)
SELECT case when one=two then 'EQUAL'
            else 'NOTEQUAL'
       end match
FROM step1
CROSS JOIN step2
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple subquery

```
Select t.*,
       case when one=two then 'EQUAL'
            else 'NOTEQUAL'
       end match
From (
    select 1 as one, 
           (select 2 from dual) as two
    from dual
) t;
```